# Append one of two images in one span with an if

Tags: jquery, html

i want to add one of two imgs in to an span with jquery.
if $mylk=0 append .li_ik1 and if $mylk>0 append .li_ik2 .
this is my code but it doesnt works:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
var mylk= <?php echo $mylk;?>;
$('.ic_lk').append(function(){
if(mylk==0) {
    $('.ic_lk').html('<img class="li_ik1" src="pc/lk.png"></img>');
    }else if(mylk>0){
    $('.ic_lk').html('<img class="li_ik2" src="pc/lkm.png"></img>'); 
}
}); });
```

what is the problem?
thanks

Comment: use var mylk = <?php echo json_encode($mylk); ?>;

Comment: mylk works fine. i try it with alert command

Comment: `<img>` is a self closing tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for;

JS fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/c3ywbLtq/

```
<script>

  $('document').ready(function() {
    var mylk = 0;

    if (mylk == 0) {
      $('.ic_lk').html('<img class="li_ik1" src="pc/lk.png"></img>');
    } else if (mylk > 0) {
      $('.ic_lk').html('<img class="li_ik2" src="pc/lkm.png"></img>');
    }
  });

</script>


<span class="ic_lk"></span>
```